# What "Insufficient Data" means for ec2 status check

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I launched a EC2 instance from AWS web UI and the "status check" shows "Insufficient Data". I am wondering what "Insufficient Data" means for ec2 status check. 
Depending on what the "data" refer to, one guess is that the machine are have not accumulated enough data to show status, if this is the case, then I can go ahead use the instance. 
Another guess is that the instance have problem acquiring data storage resource like EBS. 
Or it could mean other things. 
Is there any explanation or document about this? Thanks

Comment: Seems like an underlying ec2 host issue did you try restarting instance

Comment: @varnit Does this means there is real problem for this instance, not simply waiting for data? I will try restart now.

Comment: @varnit Restarting did not fix the issue. And I still want to know what this "Insufficient data" means.

Comment: Can you post a screenshot of thar

Comment: I launched another instance and terminated that one. So can not take screen shoot any more. The new instance is normal. Still curious about "Insufficient data"'s meaning.

Comment: Actually its not mentioned anywhere in aws documentation but after some googling i found that it sometimes occur when underlying hardware on which ec2 runs have some internal issue

Answer (score 0):

when we got alert insufficient data after some time instance will be  restarted and recovered. But it will be applicable to some instance family like M5. pleas refer  https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instance-recover.html this url

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.